# Can the categories in the postgres tablefunc crosstab() function be integers?

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab

It's all in the title. Documentation has something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM crosstab('...') AS ct(row_name text, category_1 text, category_2 text);
```

I have two tables, `lab_tests` and `lab_tests_results`. All of the `lab_tests_results` rows are tied to the primary key id integer in the `lab_tests` table. I'm trying to make a pivot table where the lab tests (identified by an integer) are row headers and the respective results are in the table. I can't get around a syntax error at or around the integer.

Is this possible with the current set up? Am I missing something in the documentation? Or do I need to perform an inner join of sorts to make the categories strings? Or modify the `lab_tests_results` table to use a text identifier for the lab tests?

Thanks for the help, all. Much appreciated.

**Edit:** Got it figured out with the help of Dmitry. He had the data layout figured out, but I was unclear on what kind of output I needed. I was trying to get the pivot table to be based on batch_id numbers in the lab_tests_results table. Had to hammer out the base query and casting data types.

```
SELECT *
 FROM crosstab('SELECT lab_tests_results.batch_id, lab_tests.test_name, lab_tests_results.test_result::FLOAT
                FROM lab_tests_results, lab_tests
                WHERE lab_tests.id=lab_tests_results.lab_test AND (lab_tests.test_name LIKE ''Test Name 1'' OR lab_tests.test_name LIKE ''Test Name 2'')
                ORDER BY 1,2'
            )   AS final_result(batch_id VARCHAR, test_name_1 FLOAT, test_name_2 FLOAT);
```

This provides a pivot table from the lab_tests_results table like below:

```
batch_id   |test_name_1 |test_name_2 
---------------------------------------
batch1     |  result1   |   <null>
batch2     |  result2   |  result3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your tables look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE lab_tests (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(500)
);

CREATE TABLE lab_tests_results (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  lab_tests_id INTEGER REFERENCES lab_tests (id),
  result TEXT
);
```

And your data looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO lab_tests (id, name) 
VALUES (1, 'test1'),
       (2, 'test2');

INSERT INTO lab_tests_results (id, lab_tests_id, result)
VALUES (1,1,'result1'),
       (2,1,'result2'),
       (3,2,'result3'),
       (4,2,'result4'),
       (5,2,'result5');
```

First of all `crosstab` is part of `tablefunc`, you need to enable it:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

You need to run it one per database as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query#answer-11751905) answer.

The final query will look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT lt.name::TEXT, lt.id, ltr.result
     FROM lab_tests AS lt
     JOIN lab_tests_results ltr ON ltr.lab_tests_id = lt.id'
) AS ct(test_name text, result_1 text, result_2 text, result_3 text);
```

**Explanation:**
The `crosstab()` function takes a text of a query which should return 3 columns; (1) a column for name of a group, (2) a column for grouping, (3) the value. The wrapping query just selects all the values those `crosstab()` returns and defines the list of columns after (the part after `AS`). First is the category name (`test_name`) and then the values (`result_1`, `result_2`). In my query I'll get up to 3 results. If I have more then 3 results then I won't see them, If I have less then 3 results I'll get nulls.

The result for this query is:

```
test_name |result_1 |result_2 |result_3
---------------------------------------
test1     |result1  |result2  |<null>
test2     |result3  |result4  |result5
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Got the output I wanted figured out from what you provided. Edited my original post to show that.